# Is it possible to emulate border-collapse (ala CSS) in a WPF ItemsControl?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, border

I'm styling the items in a WPF `ListBox`, and want to put a border around each item. With `BorderThickness` set to 1, for example, the top-bottom borders between adjacent items are both drawn and therefore appear "thicker" than the side borders, as shown:

[image: ListBoxItem border example]

The item template that produces these `ListBoxItems` is:

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" Background="DimGray" Padding="8 4 8 4">        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16"/>
  </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

I'd like to "collapse" these adjacent borders, as one could, for example, [through CSS](http://htmldog.com/reference/cssproperties/border-collapse/). I'm aware that `BorderThickness` can be defined separately for the left/right/top/bottom borders, but this affects the border of the first or last item, as well, which is not desired.

Is there a way to accomplish this with WPF? A property of `Border` I'm missing, or does it require a different approach to creating borders?

Comment: In case anyone gets here again, here it is a somewhat clever "GridLayout" implementation: http://daniel-albuschat.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/gridlayout-for-wpf-escape-margin-hell.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `BorderThickness="1,0,1,1"` and a `DataTrigger` which checks for `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}` being `null` to set `BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"`:

```
<Window x:Class="CollapseBordersDemo.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="239" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <x:Array x:Key="ListBoxItems" Type="{x:Type sys:String}">
      <sys:String>Alice</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Bob</sys:String>
      <sys:String>Colleen</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxTemplate">
      <Border x:Name="Border" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" Background="LightGray" Padding="8 4 8 4">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" FontSize="16"/>
      </Border>
      <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
          <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{StaticResource ListBoxItems}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxTemplate}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to circle back to this. This works quite well, and I prefer it to @Meleak's answer which, while similar, tortures the purpose of `AlternationIndex` somewhat (in my opinion). Accepted, thank you. :)

Comment: The PreviousData trigger had refresh problems for me, when I removed the first entry. Instead of the trigger, I put a 0,1,0,0 border to the listbox, and make the whole listbox invisble if it has no entries. Works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

One thing that comes to mind is to make use of AlternationIndex. This will require you to set something like `AlternationCount="10000"` on the ListBox. After that you can set `BorderThickess="1,0,1,1"` and use a DataTrigger to find the first ListBoxItem

```
<DataTemplate>
  <Border x:Name="border" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1" BorderBrush="DarkSlateGray" Background="DimGray" Padding="8 4 8 4">        
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="16"/>
  </Border>
  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                                   Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)}"
                 Value="0">
      <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
    </DataTrigger>
  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may add

```
 Margin="0,0,0,-1" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
```

to the border definition

Comment: That does collapse the borders, but has the unfortunate side-effect of removing the border from the bottom-most element. It looks like one of the solutions that uses a trigger to identify the first or last element and handle it separately is required.