# Is there any way to merge margins in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, margin

In HTML, for a table (at least), one can style the element so that margins are merged. I.e. two adjacent rows both have top and bottom margins of 10, so the gap between these two rows will be 20. When their margins are merged, the gap is only 10.

Is there any way to achieve this in WPF?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to emulate border-collapse (ala CSS) in a WPF ItemsControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572631/is-it-possible-to-emulate-border-collapse-ala-css-in-a-wpf-itemscontrol)

Comment: it's not a duplicate unless nothing has changed since then... it would be good to have an updated, definitive answer on this glaring omission from the wtf spec.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I had more reputation I'd mark this as a duplicate of [Is it possible to emulate border-collapse (ala CSS) in a WPF ItemsControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572631/is-it-possible-to-emulate-border-collapse-ala-css-in-a-wpf-itemscontrol) . It looks as if this is kludgeable (for a ListBox at least) using a DataTrigger to check the value of preceding entries and set borders accordingly for null values.

Comment: Thank you. Marked as duplicate myself, but still accepted yours in case this survives.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. The supposed dup is about borders. This is about margins. Completely different problem with a completely different solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this, and when you look at how WPF handles layout you'll see why, but also see that there is a hard way if you're up to it.

As you can see from the [WPF source code](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/blob/main/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Wpf/src/PresentationFramework/System/Windows/FrameworkElement.cs) for `FrameworkElement`, the `MeasureCore` sealed override method (which prevents us from overriding it further) adds the element's margins before returning with its desired size. Annoyingly, they seem to have a `BypassLayoutPolicies` option which would prevent this, but for reasons possibly ranging from short-sighted to sadistic, they made this `internal` so it's not an option. Thus the fully margined size of the element is what always winds up being assigned to `DesiredSize`, which is basically what all layout panels (`StackPanel`) etc. naively use to arrange the items during `ArrangeOverride`.

But therein is the solution, if you're willing to subclass all the panels and override their `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`. Knowing the margin values of two adjacent children you could collapse their respective right/left or bottom/top margins together during the measure and arrange passes, by just subtracting the duplicative portion of the margin from their `DesiredSize's.

But if you're gonna subclass anyway, another option, which I would consider cleaner and a better practice overall, is to add a `Spacing` property to your subclassed Panels, which exists in the [WinUI version of `StackPanel`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel.spacing?view=winrt-22621) This would require you to either ensure that your child items all have zero margins, or to subtract their actual margin values out from their `DesiredSize`'s. You would then add this spacing instead between the items during the arrange pass.

`StackPanel` is easy enough to extend this way as both passes are very simple. `Grid`, unfortunately, is a lot more complicated. `VirtualizingStackPanel` is probably out of the question... So this is by no means a silver bullet, but given how common `StackPanel` is, even just extending that control would cover a whole lot of ground and lead to much cleaner layouts IMO.